# Terminate Worklow in SharePoint Office 365 without Deleting associated task

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have three step approval workflow and for one instance of the workflow all the approves approved the workflow but still workflow status shown in In Progress and Last Approves get Email Notification hence they had approve the task.

Now If I terminate the workflow then all the Approved task will be deleted,So i want to know is there any other way so that the workflow will terminated and task will remain present and will not be deleted from the approval task list.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am answering my own question here in case someone runs across something similar.

In this case we can use the "Cancel all Task Process tasks" Link.By Clicking this link you will get the below message.
[image]

So by clicking "Yes" button All tasks will be canceled and workflow will be move to the next step after the task and In My case it will be Terminated.

Note: The task which was Approved those Outcome remain "Approved" the task whose status is "Not Started" will be canceled.

So by using this the tasks will not deleted from the "Workflow Tasks".